# 500 Internal Server Error - GoDaddy flesk server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-config

I have developed WordPress site which is working fine. When I moved it to `GoDaddy flesk server` and try to `create/edit` WordPress post or page - It gives following error:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and `web.config` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>  
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what errors you have on your error log files?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to see the log file. I did get understand

Comment: Are there any errors in server error log? More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Is there any more information in the server log? I think it is a generic Apache error meaning "some other component encountered an error"; It might be an error in your PHP script, access error in database or in file system. Or better still, contact the go daddy support or chat with them concerning this issue

Comment: Thanks, @Solar, your comment was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution of it. Just I have added `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>` in `web.config` file as:
[Get detailed errors](https://in.godaddy.com/help/get-detailed-errors-16085)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It gives following fatal error;

```
Fatal error: Class ‘MPCETemplate’ not found in C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\wp-content\plugins\motopress-content-editor\includes\ce\Library.php on line 1989
```

**Solution:** Actually, the issue was in PHP code. `Library.php` was missing in `motopress-content-editor` plugin.

Just I logged in WordPress admin panel and deactivate this `motopress-content-editor` plugin. It's started working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra/empty newline before and after "# END WordPress". It should resolve the issue.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```